# Extract substring between separators

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a way to extract data **between** multiple occuring separators.

Input:

```
$ETW$05$56$EXPENSES4500.50$
```

The task is to extract the following:

Var0:     $**ETW**$05$56$EXPENSES4500.50$ ---> **ETW**

Var1:     $ETW$**05**$56$EXPENSES4500.50$ ---> **05**

Var3:     $ETW$05$**56**$EXPENSES4500.50$ ---> **56**

Var3:     $ETW$05$56$**EXPENSES4500.50**$ ---> **EXPENSES4500.50**

Basically the aim is to get the nth occurence between two identical separators.

Comment: why not split on `$` ?

Comment: Or use lookaround `(?<=\$)[^$]+(?=\$)`

Comment: What was the problem when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

You could trim the `$` from the start and end, and then use split to generate an array:

```
inp = "$ETW$05$56$EXPENSES4500.50$"
parts = inp.strip('$').split('$')
print(parts)
```

To access a certain element, just reference the array above, e.g. for the second element use:

```
print(parts[1])
```

Note here that no regex is actually being used, just the base Python string functions.  Hence, `$` does not need to be escaped in the call to `split()`, and also we don't have to import the `re` library in our script.

Comment: Is the second element `ETW` or `05`? I presume the former.